# How to write to file without parenthesis in python

Tags: python, fwrite

When i write to file my results:

```
output=knew[i][0],knew[i][1], knew[i][2],eigenval[k],group[i]
value=str(output)
o.write(value+'\n')
```

I get:

```
(0.05, 0.05, 0.166667, -0.8513056, 0.9881956035137526)
(0.05, 1.05, 0.166667, -0.8513056, 0.011652226336523394)
(0.05, -0.9500000000000002, 0.166667, -0.8513056, 0.00015217014972403685)
```

How to write to file so it doesn't add brackets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
value = str(output)
```

you can do

```
value = ', '.join(map(str, output))
```

What you see is the string representation of a tuple. It's there because you called `str` on it.

What the [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method does is join an iterable (e.g. a tuple or a list) of strings, using the string that it's called on as a delimiter (here `', '` is the delimiter and `map(str, output)` is the iterable of strings.) into a single string. [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) applies a function to each element of an iterable. In this case, `str` is applied to each element of `output`, so that we have an iterable of strings, rather than float numbers.

Alternatively (a bit hacky) you can just strip off the parentheses from the value that you have:

```
value = str(output)[1:-1]
```

Comment: I infer the OP is rather new to Python, therefore you may wish to explain why you do `map(str, output)` and also what `', '.join` does.

Comment: Thanks. map(str, output) i found also keeps my 0.95 as that instead of 0.950000000002. Did some reading up on join and map, great functions to know.

Comment: @AntonB: That's probably because of the difference between `str` and `repr`, which you should definitely read up on. Computers can't store most floating-point decimals accurately (because they store floating-point _binary_ numbers). In earlier versions of Python, `repr` tries to show as many digits as possible. Recent (both 2.x and 3.x) versions of `repr` try to show the shortest decimal that would round to the actual binary number instead, so you don't see this as often.

Comment: @AntonB: Oh, and you probably won't figure this out from the docs on your own, but: calling `str` on a `tuple` (or other collection) doesn't call `str` on its members, but `repr`, which is why you're seeing `repr` results even though you never call it anywhere. Lev's code explicitly calls `str` on the members, so it avoids that. (This is a lot easier to see with a tuple of strings than a tuple of floats.)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    output = knew[i][0], knew[i][1], knew[i][2], eigenval[k], group[i]
    writer.writerow(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
value = "{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}".format(knew[i][0],knew[i][1], knew[i][2],eigenval[k],group[i])
o.write(value)
```

Using **format** function of str objects is a better approach. And more efficient too.

Comment: You can shorten this to `value = "{0[0]}, {0[1]}, {0[2]}, {1}, {2}".format(knew[i], eigenval[k], group[i])` since the same tuple is used for the first three fields.